# How to automatically scan the re-uploaded files with some modification in the wildfly-10 without the server restart?

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

I am using wildfly-10 server. I am providing an option to Upload images or jsp files for the user in the UI and the user can make use of these files in the other section of the application later.
At any one point of time I am allowing only one entry with a particular name. If the user tries to upload file with a name that is already existing then I am trying to overwrite the existing one with the new file.

In this scenario I am facing the below problem:

> > I have uploaded a image with the name image1.png. 
> >     Now if I change some other image's name to image1.png and upload it, the new image is not visible until I restart the server.

Looks like the older image has been cached by the server and it is still referring to the cache location. When I restart the server then it refreshes the cache with the new content of the file.

Is there any way that I can immediately see the changes in the UI whenever I re-upload the modified file?
I am using a custom folder to store the uploaded files in my server. 
Is there way that I can enable deployment directory scan for this particular directory only?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to restart the server, a redeploy of the application should work.

You can define another deployment scanner or the directory scanned by the scanner: http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/16.0/subsystem/deployment-scanner/scanner/index.html

Another solution would be to create overlays http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/16.0/deployment-overlay/index.html .

Thirdly with exploded deployments WildFly already provide the functionality you have developed: https://wildfly.org/news/2017/09/08/Exploded-deployments/ (note that all jboss-cli operations can be called using HTTP rest API)